# is there hierarchical user level structure in drupal

Tags: users

Is there any hierachical structure of user in Drupal?
I just see user role in drupal, but can we define some level of user?
As example:

```
user1
--user2
---user3
--user4
---user5
---user6
```

Comment: what do you need to user level for? I am curious because the permission-role system can give you many "hierarchies" in terms of permissions. I imagin adding the user levels as you describe could add complexity to the system. Say user6 has Role Admin, how do you handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Subuser](https://drupal.org/project/subuser) module to see if it fits your needs.

If you want "just" the roles to be hierarchical, [Role delegation](https://drupal.org/project/role_delegation) might be useful

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281964/drupal-for-users-creating-sub-users

Answer (score 1):

For handling hierarchies, I prefer to use [organic groups](https://drupal.org/project/og) and sometimes [og_subgroups](https://drupal.org/project/og_subgroups).  This gives you hierarchies of groups rather than hierarchies of users, but I have used this, for example, to make a hierarchy of "officers", and other group members are the officer's assistants.  The other advantage of hierarchy of groups over a hierarchy of users is that it is possible for one user to appear at multiple places in the hierarchy, if necessary.